# Preventing freezing while using live image display in Tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter

I have a function `get_image()` which acquires an image from the camera at some `exposure_time`. I have another function `find_features()` which finds some interesting features in the image and usually takes about ~5-10s to run.

Right now I have these functions called within Tkinter's `update()` function, and then an `after()` call within `update()` to re-run `update()` after a period of `exposure_time`, but this causes the GUI to freeze for many seconds.

How can I display an image onto the GUI as soon as it's been acquired (so approximately a new image occurs with a period equal to the exposure time of the camera) and then using this image, run `find_features()` while keeping the GUI responsive?

`find_features()` also returns some values that are useful for updating some parameters within the GUI.

Comment: I'd probably do the image acquisition and processing in another thread and have it post results via a `queue.Queue` that you'd read in a periodical `after()` handler.

Comment: Can you give us a [mre] to work with?

Comment: You'll find a lot of information here on SO about threading or also here https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think official `Queue` [example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) is quite good fit for this:

With a simple modification, and adding two queues for two different types of work;

```
import threading
import queue

q_image = queue.Queue()
q_features = queue.Queue()

def image_worker():
    while True:
        payload = q_image.get()
        img = get_image()
        payload['callback'](img)
        q_image.task_done()


def features_worker():
    while True:
        payload = q_features.get()
        img = find_features()
        payload['callback'](img)
        q_features.task_done()

# Turn-on the worker threads.
threading.Thread(target=image_worker, daemon=True).start()
threading.Thread(target=features_worker, daemon=True).start()

def wherever_you_set_the_ui():
    features_widget = ...
    img_widget = ...
    def show_features(image):
        # update the features in the Tkinter widget.
        features_widget.configure(image=image)
        features_widget.image = image

    def show_image(image):
        # update the image in the Tkinter widget.
        img_widget.configure(image=image)
        img_widget.image = image
        q_features.put({'some_payload': ..., 'callback': show_features})

    # Add your request to queue (e.g. from button click) with the payload needed
    q_image.put({'some_payload': ..., 'callback': show_image})
```

I didn't test the code but I think it conveys the idea.